# why does this pipe work on local mock data but not incoming data from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Someone provided me with this plunker to accomplish something I need to do.
https://plnkr.co/edit/q9olLVsEcGrskv8oQkV7?p=preview

I played around with it and used it on my own mock data which looks like this.

```
links = [ {
      link  : 'I need to expand my current brand.',
      val   : 'expand'
  }, {
      link  : 'I need to re-create my Brand.',
      val   : 'recreate'
  }, {
      link  : 'I need to build a Brand for my new Business.',
      val   : 'new-business'
  }, {
      link  : 'I need to build a Brand for my new product.',
      val   : 'new-product'
  }, {
      link  : 'I have a technical difficulty that requires an Artist.',
      val   : 'tech-difficulty'
  } ]
```

works like a charm.  However when I connect a variable containing my Firebase data, which looks like this.

```
"home_intro_links" : {
    "link01" : {
        "link"  : "I need to expand my current brand.",
        "val"   : "expand"
    },
    "link02" : {
        "link"  : "I need to re-create my brand.",
        "val"   : "recreate"
    },
    "link03" : {
        "link"  : "I need to build a brand for my new Business.",
        "val"   : "new-business"
    },
    "link04" : {
        "link"  : "I need to build a brand for my new product.",
        "val"   : "new-product"
    },
    "link05" : {
        "link"  : "I have a technical difficulty that requires an Artist.",
        "val"   : "tech-difficulty"
    }
}
```

it just flat out won't work no matter what I've tried to do.

Here's how I'm calling the data.

//the service file

```
import { Injectable }           from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire,
    FirebaseListObservable,
    FirebaseObjectObservable }  from 'angularfire2';
import { Observable }           from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable
export class HomeService {
    HomeIntroLinks: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

    constructor(private af: AngularFire) {}

    getHomeIntroLinks(){
        this.HomeIntroLinks = this.af.database.list('/home_intro_links') as FirebaseListObservable<any>
            return this.HomeIntroLinks;
    }
}
```

//the component

```
import { Component, OnInit,
    Pipe, PipeTransform }       from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire,
    FirebaseListObservable,
    FirebaseObjectObservable }  from 'angularfire2';
import { HomeService }          from '../home.service';

@Pipe({name: 'homeIntroPipe'})

export class HomeIntroPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(arr: any, linkSize: number) {
        return arr.reduce((prev, cur, index) => (index % linkSize) ?
            prev : prev.concat([arr.slice(index, index + linkSize)]), []);
  }
}

@Component({
    moduleId:     module.id,
    selector:     'home-intro',
    templateUrl:  './home-intro.component.html',
    styleUrls:    ['./home-intro.component.css'],
    providers:    [ HomeService ]
})

export class HomeIntroComponent implements OnInit{
    homeIntroLinks: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

    constructor(private _homeService: HomeService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._homeService.getHomeIntroLinks().subscribe(HomeIntroLinks =>{
            this.homeIntroLinks = HomeIntroLinks;
                //console.log(this.homeIntroLinks);
            });
    }
}
```

//the html in the template

```
<div *ngFor="let links of homeIntroLinks" class="row home_link_container justify-content-center">
   <div *ngFor="let link of links" class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
         <p class="home_link" [routerLink]="'/home/'+link.val" routerLinkActivate="active">
            {{link.link}}
         </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it just me and the way I'm doing things?.... or is there something drastically different about calling on a local variable?  So far I've tried the `json` pipe, I've tried adding `json.parse()` both in the service and in the component, nothing seems to make the data from Firebase behave the same way.  If you'd like to know errors I've been encountering with anything in particular let me know so I can go re-try it and see what it throws back.  At this point I can't remember all of them of the top of my head lol.

> UPDATE for AJT_82

Here's a screenshot of my console

[image: console view]

I tired your next solution.  The browser said it didn't recognize `firebaseObj` so I defined it in the class as `firebaseObj;`... not sure of what else to do with it. Then I got another error with it not recognizing it so I had to add `.this` to it so now it looks like this in my `@OnInit`

```
this.firebaseObj = this._homeService.getHomeIntroLinks()
        this.homeIntroLinks = Object.keys(this.firebaseObj).map(x => this.firebaseObj[x])
```

now I'm back to the `[object object]` issue.  Here's a screen shot of the console.

[image: screenshot 02]

Comment: thanks for the update, error suggests that that it's not an array that it's trying to iterate, but rather an object perhaps. Could you just console log in the mapping, so we know for sure how the incoming data looks like. `.map((res: Response) => { console.log('res', res); })` and post the response in your question. As a comment, in my answer we indeed tried to map the incoming data to an array, but seems to not be working. So print the incoming data, so that it will be easier to find a solution. Thanks :)

Comment: the last picture I posted of the console is the result of doing the `.map`, no data came.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [async](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html) pipe with an observable.

```
<div *ngFor="let links of homeIntroLinks | async" class="row home_link_container justify-content-center">
  ...
</div>
```

Simplified view to see the results:

```
  <div *ngFor="let links of HomeIntroLinks | async" class="row home_link_container justify-content-center">
    {{links.link}}
  </div>
```

Comment: It will work but your html doesn't match the objects returned. links.link is a string and is not iterable. I will edit the answer and out a simplified bit of markup in so you can see the results of the Firebase query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in service:

```
 getHomeIntroLinks(){
    this.HomeIntroLinks = this.af.database.list('/home_intro_links') 
        return this.HomeIntroLinks;
 }
```

and in component:

```
homeIntroLinks; // remove the typing to firebaseobservable (for now)

ngOnInit() {
    this.homeIntroLinks = this._homeService.getHomeIntroLinks()
}
```

here you would perhaps need to add the async pipe in the template:

```
*ngFor="let links of homeIntroLinks | async"
```

---

Else, if it happens to be a object that gets returned from your firebase, map the keys and create an array instead:

```
ngOnInit() {
    firebaseObj = this._homeService.getHomeIntroLinks()
    this.homeIntroLinks = Object.keys(firebaseObj).map(x => firebaseObj[x])  
}
```

then for app not throwing error because of loading the view before data has arrived it could be wise to wrap everything inside `div` with: `<div *ngIf="homeIntroLinks"> ... </div>`

Comment: I tried them both and am getting an error saying it can't find the name `Response` pointing at the service file on both of them.

Comment: and that was after I added `<any>` after the `FirebaseListObservable`, it said it couldn't be used without a type.  I tried deleting `<any>` from mine to see if it made a difference and the console just went through each one giving the `<T>` error/reminder.

Comment: Well, as Aravind pointed out the difference between the static and the fb-data, so I updated my answer with transforming the object to an array Check my updated answer :)

Comment: it's still telling me `cannot find name Response` in the service file.

Comment: Import response to your service, and that problem should be gone: `import { Response } from '@angular/http';`

Comment: ok now I'm getting an error saying `Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable<any>'` coming from the component.

Comment: Updated answer, you are trying to assign an array to an object (I assume FirebaseListObservable is an object). So change accordingly, that homeIntroLinks is an array of FirebaseListObservable.

Comment: now it's saying this `Generic type 'FirebaseListObservable<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).`

Comment: nothing logs in the console.  Still getting the firebase error. and I'm not using any classes or templates.  When I went into studying on how to load data into them from firebase, that's when I fond `json.parse()` which converts it into a javascript object.

Comment: Yeah, check how that incoming data looks like, just to make sure, so do this in map `.map((res: Response) => { console.log('res', res); })` so we know for sure if it's an array or object that is coming in :)

Comment: But that's what I just tried, it won't log anything because of the type on `FirebaseListObservable`, I tried switching it back to `<any>` and it's back to saying it cant apply `any[]` to it.

Comment: Oookayh. updated my answer again. Let's just strip everything away and try the above :D Both possibilities are there, in case there is an array or object returned. Try if either works, really hope so :D :D

Comment: I just updated my question with a screenshot of the console. Thanks for taking the time to work with me on this, it has officially been one week I've been stuck at this, I ran out of other stuff to do that doesn't involve this 2 days ago lol.

Answer (score 0):

Your firebase should be sending the data in this format

```
 [{
  "link01": {
    "link": "I need to expand my current brand.",
    "val": "expand"
  },
  "link02": {
    "link": "I need to re-create my brand.",
    "val": "recreate"
  },
  "link03": {
    "link": "I need to build a brand for my new Business.",
    "val": "new-business"
  },
  "link04": {
    "link": "I need to build a brand for my new product.",
    "val": "new-product"
  },
  "link05": {
    "link": "I have a technical difficulty that requires an Artist.",
    "val": "tech-difficulty"
  }
}]
```

You can use map operator to convert the returned data as json format in your service as

```
 getTasks(): Observable<any[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._url)
            .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log("data we got is " + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/TAAEVz7bMwOPZAM5C8H1?p=info)**